# How to put wedge and vee inside box?

Tags: math-mode, box

I want to put \wedge and \vee in a box like in the image.

[image]

I have tried \framebox, but didnt work.

Comment: Try `\fbox` with `\fboxsep=0pt`

Comment: nobody has mentioned that these symbols should be available in the stix fonts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can box the symbols `\vee` and `\wedge`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\boxedsymbol}[2]{%
  \begingroup
  \setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}%
  \fbox{%
    $\m@th#1\mspace{-1.25mu}#2\mspace{-1.25mu}$%
  }%
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother
\newcommand{\boxvee}{\mathbin{\mathpalette\boxedsymbol\vee}}
\newcommand{\boxwedge}{\mathbin{\mathpalette\boxedsymbol\wedge}}

\begin{document}

$\varepsilon_{A}(\mathbf{x})=A^{t}\boxwedge\mathbf{x}$

$\delta_{A}(\mathbf{x})=A^{t}\boxvee\mathbf{x}$

$
{\boxvee}\ {\boxwedge}\ 
\scriptstyle
{\boxvee}\ {\boxwedge}\ 
\scriptscriptstyle
{\boxvee}\ {\boxwedge}
$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Depending on the math font you may need to adjust the 1.25mu length.

A refined version with different rule thickness and some more adjustments.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\boxedsymbol}[2]{%
  \begingroup
  \setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}%
  \setlength{\fboxrule}{\variable@rule{#1}}%
  \fbox{%
    $\m@th#1\variable@space{#1}#2\variable@space{#1}$%
  }%
  \endgroup
}
\newcommand{\variable@rule}[1]{%
  \fontdimen8  
  \ifx#1\displaystyle\textfont3\else
    \ifx#1\textstyle\textfont3\else
      \ifx#1\scriptstyle\scriptfont3\else
        \scriptscriptfont3\relax
  \fi\fi\fi
}
\newcommand{\variable@space}[1]{%
  \mspace{-
    \ifx#1\displaystyle 1.25\else
      \ifx#1\textstyle 1.25\else
        \ifx#1\scriptstyle 1.4\else
          1.6%
    \fi\fi\fi
  mu}%
}
\makeatother
\newcommand{\boxvee}{\mathbin{\mathpalette\boxedsymbol\vee}}
\newcommand{\boxwedge}{\mathbin{\mathpalette\boxedsymbol\wedge}}

\begin{document}

$\varepsilon_{A}(\mathbf{x})=A^{t}\boxwedge\mathbf{x}$

$\delta_{A}(\mathbf{x})=A^{t}\boxvee\mathbf{x}$

$
{\boxvee}\ {\boxwedge}\ 
\scriptstyle
{\boxvee}\ {\boxwedge}\ 
\scriptscriptstyle
{\boxvee}\ {\boxwedge}
$

{\large$\boxvee\ \scriptstyle\boxvee$}

{\footnotesize$\boxvee\ \scriptstyle\boxvee$}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: why isn't the `\fboxsep=0pt` less susceptible to variations in font dimensions?

Comment: @barbarabeeton Do you mean the `\fboxrule`? One can try and set it based on the font size, but it's always a hack.

Comment: going by memory (out of my element for a while), there is a defined gap between the rule and the content of the `\fbox`.  that is what i was aiming at.

Comment: @barbarabeeton The symbols have different sidebearings at different sizes. I provided a refined version.

Answer (score 5):

A 'dirty' version with TikZ and yellow background ;-)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\tightbox}[1]{%
  \tikz{\node[rectangle,fill=yellow,draw,inner sep=0.25pt,line width=0.25pt] (A) {$#1$};}%
}

\begin{document}
$\vee$ \tightbox{\vee}  \tightbox{\wedge}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yellow background? Duck, duck! ;-)

Comment: @PrzemysławScherwentke: It's GroundDuck day ;-)